# Snmp not responding on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, nfs, snmp

We have a Ubuntu 14.04 on our machine. We have a program that use network aggressively, It reads files from mounted NFS directories. When we run it snmp requests to machine got timeout.

So, my question is what makes snmp service to not respond? We suspected to network, but if the problem is network and our program is saturating network, why other network services like SSH and JMX are working without trouble?

Comment: Perhaps `tail -20 /var/log/syslog | grep -i snmp` would help